Quiero que los resultados aparezcan filas y no en columnas css php
Estimados de antemano muchas gracias, quiero que el contenido de la tabla se muestre en filas ej: nombre juanito, y debajo numero 123, y asi consecutivamente, espero puedan ayudarme e intentado varias formas en css y nada, gracias
``` 
<table class="pass">
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
        
            <th>Numero</th>
        
            <th>Invitado</th>
            
            <th>Hora Inicio</th>
             
            <th>Hora Fin</th>
                      
        </tr><?php 
       
       if($result){
            $limitedResults = array_slice($result, 0, 10); // Limitar a 10 resultados
            foreach ($limitedResults as $key => $value) {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value['nombre'];?></td>
                   
                    <td><?php echo $value['numero'];?></td>
                   
                    <td><?php echo $value['invitado'];?></td>
               
                    <td><?php echo $value['inicio'];?></td>
                    
                    <td><?php echo $value['fin'];?></td>
                                      
                </tr>
                <?php
```

            


y que has intentado para hacerlo como dices???

Supongo te refieres a algo como esto:
    <table>
        <caption>El titulo de nuestra tabla</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <td><?php echo $value['nombre'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Numero</th>
            <td><?php echo $value['numero'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Invitado</th>
            <td><?php echo $value['invitado'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Inicio</th>
            <td><?php echo $value['inicio'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Fin</th>
            <td><td><?php echo $value['fin'];?></td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Sea el caso, te recomiendo ver CSS. Podrias usar CSS grid; en caso de que no te manejes con CSS, utiliza ChatGPT y que te cree algo bonito y sencillo, solo escribe la misma pregunta que hiciste aqui, pasas tu codigo y te lo hace.
Hay que jugar con herramientas asi jaja

Creo que lo que buscas hacer es un "Vertical Heading"
Lo puedes ver en: Vertical Headings
Para ello debes reordenar las filas y columnas de la tabla
Ahora, Suponiendo que $result es un arreglo asociativo con la información de la base de datos, puedes hacer un foreach para generar la tabla de la manera que deseas, sin que se repita la cabecera por cada registro.
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        if ($result) {
            $limitedResults = array_slice($result, 0, 10);
            $headers = ['Nombre', 'Número', 'Invitado', 'Hora Inicio', 'Hora Fin'];
            $keys = ['nombre', 'numero', 'invitado', 'inicio', 'fin'];
            
            foreach ($headers as $index => $header) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th class="table-dark" >' . $header . '</th>';
                foreach ($limitedResults as $record) {
                    echo '<td>' . $record[$keys[$index]] . '</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

Si requieres modificar los campos de la tabla simplemente agrega o quita en $headers y $keys.
Puedes añadir Bootstrap para los estilos de la tabla, ubícalo dentro de tu <head> ... </head>.
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

Obteniendo algo como:

Las clases table table-bordered table-hover table-dark son de Bootstrap, si no las ocupas simplemente quítalas.
Suerte!
